# ubuntu 12.04 no kernl at grub startup

Tags: grub, ubuntu-12.04

I have a virtualbox virtual machine on Windows 10 that launch linux Ubuntu 12.04. 
On startup, grub don't find any kernel to boot on, so it start a memtest sequence. 
I use an Ubuntu 16.04 livecd to mount my 12.04 system, chroot, and reinstall grub. But nothing change, I always have same problem.
Is it a kernel installation problem ? How can I check this ?
Any other idea please ?

Edit 1 :
My /boot/ folder contain only grub directory and memtest*.bin... Nothing else, no vmlinuz and co... How can I reinstall this ?

Edit 2 :
Reinstall the kernel (after booting with live cd and chroot) with command `apt-get -V install linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic` solve the problem. Don't forget to `sudo upgrade-grub` after.

Comment: Have you checked that you are booting from the right drive in your BIOS?

Comment: Yes I have just one drive available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall the kernel (after booting with live cd and chroot) with command `apt-get -V install linux-generic linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic` solve the problem. Don't forget to `sudo upgrade-grub` after.